# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3100

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am new to node.I get the error that is *Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3100*, when I run npm test.

This is my test file.

**Test.ts**

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
import * as assert from 'assertthat';
import * as request from "superagent";
chai.use(chaiHttp);
const expect = chai.expect;
describe('Checking whether the response return status 200', function() {
it('Status OK', function(done) {
return chai.request('https://localhost:3100') 
.get('/hello')
.end(function(err, res){
    if(err){
        done(err);
    }
    else{
        expect(res.body.message).to.equal('hello world');
        done();
    }
});
});
});
```

This is my app file

**app.ts**

```
import * as express from 'express';
import {Request,Response} from 'express';
const app: express.Express = express();

app.get('/hello',(req:Request,res:Response)=>{
    res.json({
        message:"hello world"
    });
});
app.listen(3100,() =>{
    console.log("server listening");
});
export default app;
```

Comment: You are listening on the port 6000 and try a request on the 3100. Try to change the port number to 6000 in your Test

Comment: Sorry..Its 3100 @Kerberos

Comment: Mocha supports Promises, so this code can be vastly simplified, especially using `async`/`await`.

Comment: @tadman I submit and edit for this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is not running while trying to test **GET /hello** route which is why it fails to connect.

See here an [example](https://blog.khophi.co/mocha-chai-chai-http-test-express-api-auth-endpoints/https://blog.khophi.co/mocha-chai-chai-http-test-express-api-auth-endpoints/) on how you should test your API's server routes.

Within your *test.ts* file, you should import your server and make sure it **listen** before tests and **close** after tests.

```
import server from 'app.ts';
import * as chai from 'chai';
import * as assert from 'assertthat';
import * as request from 'superagent';

const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const expect = chai.expect;

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Checking whether the response return status 200', function() {
    it('Status OK', async function(done) {
        const { res, err } = await chai.request(server).get('/hello');
        expect(res.body.message).to.equal('hello world');
    });
});
```

Comment: Careful here. This expects `done()` to be called, or a function with zero arguments.