# Jest test passed but get Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 at the end

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm using node with TypeScript on my back end and Jest and Supertest as my test framework on my back end.

When I'm trying to test I have the result pass but I get an error at the end. Here's the result:

```
 PASS  test/controllers/user.controller.test.ts
  Get all users
    ✓ should return status code 200 (25ms)

  console.log node_modules/@overnightjs/logger/lib/Logger.js:173
    [2019-12-05T04:54:26.811Z]: Setting up database ...

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.284s
Ran all test suites.
server/test/controllers/user.controller.test.ts:32
                throw err;
                ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1104:14)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Here's my test code:

```
import request from "supertest";
import { AppServer } from '../../config/server';

const server = new AppServer();

describe('Get all users', () => {
  it('should return status code 200', async () => {
    server.startDB();
    const appInstance = server.appInstance;
    const req = request(appInstance);
    req.get('api/v1/users/')
      .expect(200)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) throw err;
      })
  })
})
```

Here's my server setup. I'm using `overnightjs` on my back end.

I created a getter to get the Express instance. This is coming from overnight.js.

```
// this should be the very top, should be called before the controllers
require('dotenv').config();

import 'reflect-metadata';

import { Server } from '@overnightjs/core';
import { Logger } from '@overnightjs/logger';
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as controllers from '../src/controllers/controller_imports';

export class AppServer extends Server {
  constructor() {
    super(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development');
    this.app.use(helmet());
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
    this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    this.setupControllers();
  }

  get appInstance(): any {
    return this.app;
  }

  private setupControllers(): void {
    const controllerInstances = [];

    // eslint-disable-next-line
    for (const name of Object.keys(controllers)) {
      const Controller = (controllers as any)[name];
      if (typeof Controller === 'function') {
        controllerInstances.push(new Controller());
      }
    }

    /* You can add option router as second argument */
    super.addControllers(controllerInstances);
  }

  private startServer(portNum?: number): void {
    const port = portNum || 8000;
    this.app.listen(port, () => {
      Logger.Info(`Server Running on port: ${port}`);
    });
  }

  /**
   * start Database first then the server
   */
  public async startDB(): Promise<any> {
    Logger.Info('Setting up database ...');
    try {
      await createConnection();
      this.startServer();
      Logger.Info('Database connected');
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.Warn(error);
      return Promise.reject('Server Failed, Restart again...');
    }
  }
}
```

I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503075/error-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-13100) - that's why I called the method `startDB`.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

So I figured out and the solution is quite easy. I can't explain why though.

This `req.get('api/v1/users/')` should be `/api/v1/users` - you need a leading `/`.

Comment: It makes complete sense that this works. here is why: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/what-is-the-purpose-of-leading-slash-in-html-urls

Answer (score 9):

For Frontend...

If you are making use of `axios` and come across this error, go to the `testSetup.js` file and add this line

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://yourbaseurl.com/"
```

This worked for me. So, typically, this is a baseURL issue.

Comment: Though I wouldn't go into a global file I find this information very useful. Thank you. :)

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it for me. Just wanted to add that you need to import `import axios from "axios";` before setting the default baseURL.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error in my React frontend app tests.

I was using [React testing library's](https://testing-library.com/) `findBy*` function in my assert:

```js
expect(await screen.findByText('first')).toBeInTheDocument();
expect(await screen.findByText('second')).toBeInTheDocument();
expect(await screen.findByText('third')).toBeInTheDocument();
```

After I changed it to:

```js
await waitFor(async () => {
  expect(await screen.findByText('first')).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(await screen.findByText('second')).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(await screen.findByText('third')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

the error is gone.

I don't know exactly why, but maybe it will help someone

**UPDATE**: I was mocking `fetch` incorrectly, so my test called real API and caused that error

I put this line in my `setupTests` file:

```js
global.fetch = jest.fn()
```

It mocks fetch for all tests globally. Then, you can mock specific responses right in your tests:

```js
jest.mocked(global.fetch).mockResolvedValue(...)
// OR
jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockResolvedValue(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the issue was related to package `react-inlinesvg`. Package makes a `fetch` request to get the `svg` file and since server is not running, it gets redirected to default `127.0.0.1:80`.
I mocked `react-inlinesvg` globally to output props including `svg` filename to assert in testing.

```
jest.mock('react-inlinesvg', () => (props) => (
    <svg data-testid="mocked-svg">{JSON.stringify(props)}</svg>
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different issue, but same error message...

I was having this error when using node-fetch when trying to connect to my own localhost (`http://localhost:4000/graphql`), and after trying what felt like everything under the sun, my most reliable solution was:

using this script in package.json: `"test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --watch"`
If the terminal shows connection error I just go to the terminal with Jest watching and press `a` to rerun all tests and they pass without any issue.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Success rate continued to improve by renaming the testing folder to `__tests__` and moving my `index.js` to `src/index.js`.

Very strange, but I am too exhausted to look at the Jest internals to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get to the bottom of this error - it wasn't related to the (accepted) leading slash answer.

However, my "fix" was to move the mocks up into the suite definition - into `beforeAll` and `afterAll` for cleanup between tests).

Before, I was mocking (`global.fetch`) in **each** test, and it was the last test in the suite to use the mock that would cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

The rules for supertest are the same as the rules for express. OvernightJS does not require any leading or ending "/" though.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing on this, but not having issues with trailing slashes:

`jest` can also return a `ECONNREFUSED` when your express app takes some time (even just a second) to restart/init. If you are using `nodemon` like me, you can disable restarts for test files like `--ignore *.test.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs if you have not set up a server to catch the request at all (depending on your implementation code and your test, the test may still pass).